# Do I only get 360 reputation a day on SO?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I've just noticed that my reputation is at 360 in SO and nothing I do (getting upvoted, upvoting, commenting, etc...) changes my reputation at all.  It's not even showing in the reputation logger.

Comment: I noticed the same thing on Programmers, but mine stopped at 200. Is this a thing?

Comment: That's very impressive to hit the cap on your first day. You're both off to great starts.

Comment: Deleting my answer and just linking to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: Registered user, completely filled-out profile, member for 2 days, rep capped on 1st day...I'm aghast!  We can't have this!

Comment: @mmyers I'm glad you think it's impressive.  I've long since hit that limit, and I has a six hour nap inbetween registering and starting posting again :/.  I could have had 1K rep today if I were all at it.

Comment: Dude...you're making the rest of us look bad. :)

Comment: Though it's not becoming to beg to be marked as the answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970270/how-to-cast-variable-to-array/5970283#5970283

Comment: @Rick, I was just curious as to why it wasn't moving is all :).  I posted another question, to continue on this thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know [this is a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), however:

Quoting the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) found in the top right corner of each page:

> A maximum of 30 votes can be cast per user per day, and you can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit). Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate reputation.

Comment: I was going to say, I'm well past that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've hit the 200 rep/day from upvotes rep cap. You still get rep from getting your answers accepted, but you won't get any more from votes until tomorrow (00:00Z).

Comment: which happens in a couple hours, yes?

Comment: In one hour, approx.  I run on UTC :D

Comment: Two hours, actually. The timestamp on this answer shows 21:53Z